# Moving `tcolorbox` inside `enumerate`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, tcolorbox

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\newcommand{\toright}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}%
}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\begin{document}
    Text
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item text
        \begin{flushleft}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=white,sharp corners, left=5pt]
                text.
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{flushleft}
        \item text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I want to move the box to the left and align it to the enumerate list. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems that you want to interrupt the `enumerate` environment by the box, so you could stop the enumeration, typeset the box, and then resume the enumeration.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{enumerate}[(a),resume]
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grow to left by=\the\leftmargin` (section 4.15.3 Toggle Enlargements in the tcolorbox documentation.)

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
With \verb|itemindent=*,align=left|
\begin{enumerate}[(a),itemindent=*,align=left]
\DrawEnumitemLabel%<-- doc enumitem p.6
\item leftmargin : \the\leftmargin
\begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=\the\leftmargin]
text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \DrawEnumitemLabel%<-- doc enumitem p.6
    \item leftmargin : \the\leftmargin
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=\the\leftmargin]
    text.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \item text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]